# Where can I find the complete English translation of Astanga Hridaya?

Tags: translation-request, ayurveda

Astanga Hridaya is one of the great texts on Ayurveda by Vagbhata.

It can be divided into five parts:

1. SUTRASTHANA
2. SARIRA STHANA
3. NIDANA STHANA
4. CIKITSITA STHANA
5. KALPASIDDHI STHANA and
6. UTTARASTHANA

I can find [SUTRASTHANA](https://www.planetayurveda.com/ayurveda-ebooks/astanga-hridaya-sutrasthan-handbook.pdf) only online.

Where can I find the remaining translations of the scripture?

Comment: You want physical books or soft copies?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Soft copy only. If not available, then physical book.

Comment: Om Namah Shanti...

Answer (score 1):

https://www.amazon.in/ASTANGA-HRIDAYA-Vagbhata-Vol-Translation/dp/9381608903 You can buy this book with all sthanas translated from here.

Or if you know sanskrit very well and can translate https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/vagbhatta/vagbhatta_sutra.pdf here sanskrit text is present.

https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/upaveda/ayurveda/astanga-hrdayam-by-vagbhata-i here you can find english translation to all sthanas for free

Answer (score 1):

For Sutra Sthana and Sarira sthan, [this](https://www.pdfdrive.com/astanga-hrdayapdf-download-e34968898.html) is the link. Rest of them are available [here.](https://archive.org/details/astangahrdayam0002unse) But in place of downloading, I would prefer to buy them from [here.](http://www.vedicbooks.net/astanga-hrdayam-volumes-p-13495.html)